# Split column in a Pandas Dataframe into n number of columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

In a column in a Pandas Dataframe, I have strings like this:

| column_name_1 | column_name_2 |
| --- | --- |
| a^b^c | j |
| e^f^g | k^l |
| h^i | m |

I need to split these strings into columns in the same data frame, like this

| column_name_1 | column_name_2 | column_name_1_1 | column_name_1_2 | column_name_1_3 | column_name_2_1 | column_name_2_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a^b^c | j | a | b | c | j |  |
| e^f^g | k^l | e | f | g | k | l |
| h^i | m | h | i |  | m |  |

I cannot figure out how to do this without knowing in advance how many occurrences of the delimiter there is in the data.

My best effort either includes something like

```
df[["column_name_1_1","column_name_1_2 ","column_name_1_3"]] = df["column_name_1"].str.split('^',n=2, expand=True)
```

But it failes with a

> ValueError: The columns in the computed data do not match the columns
> in the provided metadata

Comment: Weird, the table looks fine when I edit the question

Comment: In the second table, where did `^d` go?

Comment: I removed it from the first table @richardec. Thank you

Comment: Note: this is very similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71493347/split-column-in-a-dask-dataframe-into-n-number-of-columns, but since I forgot to mention that I am using Dask, and not vanilla Pandas, the answers here will not work, unfortunately. Dask is not supporting stack() at the moment (github.com/dask/dask/issues/7088)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try it with `stack` + `str.split` + `unstack` + `join`.

The idea is to split each column by `^` and expand the split characters into a separate column. `stack` helps us do a single `str.split` on a Series object and `unstack` creates a DataFrame with the same index as the original.

```
tmp = df.stack().str.split('^', expand=True).unstack(level=1).sort_index(level=1, axis=1)
tmp.columns = [f'{y}_{x+1}' for x, y in tmp.columns]
out = df.join(tmp).dropna(how='all', axis=1).fillna('')
```

Output:

```
  column_name_1 column_name_2 column_name_1_1 column_name_1_2 column_name_1_3 column_name_1_4 column_name_2_1 column_name_2_2  
0       a^b^c^d             j               a               b               c               d               j                  
1         e^f^g           k^l               e               f               g                               k               l  
2           h^i             m               h               i                                               m
```

Answer (score 1):

One-liner:

```
new_df = pd.concat([df] + [pd.DataFrame([pd.Series(s) for s in df[col].str.split('^')]).add_prefix(c.name + '_') for col in df], axis=1).fillna('')
```

Output:

```
>>> new_df
  column_name_1 column_name_2 column_name_1_0 column_name_1_1 column_name_1_2 column_name_1_3 column_name_1_0 column_name_1_1
0       a^b^c^d             j               a               b               c               d               j
1         e^f^g           k^l               e               f               g                               k               l
2           h^i             m               h               i                                               m
```