# Split column in a Dask Dataframe into n number of columns

Tags: python, pandas, dask, dask-dataframe

In a column in a **Dask** Dataframe, I have strings like this:

| column_name_1 | column_name_2 |
| --- | --- |
| a^b^c | j |
| e^f^g | k^l |
| h^i | m |

I need to split these strings into columns in the same data frame, like this

| column_name_1 | column_name_2 | column_name_1_1 | column_name_1_2 | column_name_1_3 | column_name_2_1 | column_name_2_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a^b^c | j | a | b | c | j |  |
| e^f^g | k^l | e | f | g | k | l |
| h^i | m | h | i |  | m |  |

I cannot figure out how to do this without knowing in advance how many occurrences of the delimiter there are in the data. Also, there are tens of columns in the Dataframe that are to be left alone, so I need to be able to specify which columns to split like this.

My best effort either includes something like

```
df[["column_name_1_1","column_name_1_2 ","column_name_1_3"]] = df["column_name_1"].str.split('^',n=2, expand=True)
```

But it fails with a

> ValueError: The columns in the computed data do not match the columns in the provided metadata

Comment: Note: this is very similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71489282/split-column-in-a-pandas-dataframe-into-n-number-of-columns, but since I forgot to mention that I am using Dask, and not vanilla Pandas, the answers in those are not relevant, unfortunately.  

Dask is not supporting stack() at the moment (https://github.com/dask/dask/issues/7088)

Comment: And what is problem with second solution?

Comment: It seems to run immediately, and not  when I call  df.to_csv()

Answer (score 1):

Here are 2 solutions working without `stack` but with loop for selected columns names:

```
cols = ['column_name_1','column_name_2']
for c in cols:
    df = df.join(df[c].str.split('^',n=2, expand=True).add_prefix(f'{c}_').fillna(''))

print (df)
  column_name_1 column_name_2 column_name_1_0 column_name_1_1 column_name_1_2  \
0         a^b^c             j               a               b               c   
1         e^f^g           k^l               e               f               g   
2           h^i             m               h               i                   

  column_name_2_0 column_name_2_1  
0               j                  
1               k               l  
2               m
```

Or modify another solution:

```
cols = ['column_name_1','column_name_2']
dfs = [df[c].str.split('^',n=2, expand=True).add_prefix(f'{c}_').fillna('') for c in cols]
df = pd.concat([df] + dfs, axis=1)
print (df)
  column_name_1 column_name_2 column_name_1_0 column_name_1_1 column_name_1_2  \
0         a^b^c             j               a               b               c   
1         e^f^g           k^l               e               f               g   
2           h^i             m               h               i                   

  column_name_2_0 column_name_2_1  
0               j                  
1               k               l  
2               m
```

Comment: using your first solution, I am getting the following error:
ValueError: The columns in the computed data do not match the columns in the provided metadata
  Extra:   []
  Missing: [2]
Do you have any idea?

Comment: I am getting this in the second example as well. Do you think this has to do with the data?

Comment: @Fontanka16 - I find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52248566/valueerror-the-columns-in-the-computed-data-do-not-match-the-columns-in-the-pro), seems some data related problem.

Comment: I'll check and accept the answer as soon as i get it to work. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately using [`dask.dataframe.Series.str.split`](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/generated/dask.dataframe.Series.str.split.html) with `expand=True` and an unknown number of splits is not yet supported in Dask, the following returns a `NotImplementedError`:

```py
import dask.dataframe as dd
import pandas as pd

ddf = dd.from_pandas(
    pd.DataFrame({
        'column_name_1': ['a^b^c', 'e^f^g', 'h^i'], 'column_name_2': ['j', 'k^l', 'm']
    }), npartitions=2
)

# returns NotImplementedError
ddf['column_name_1'].str.split('^', expand=True).compute()
```

Usually when a pandas equivalent has not yet been implemented in Dask, [`map_partitions`](https://docs.dask.org/en/stable/generated/dask.dataframe.DataFrame.map_partitions.html) can be used to apply a Python function on each DataFrame partition. In this case, however, Dask would still need to know how many columns to expect in order to lazily produce a Dask DataFrame, as provided with a [`meta`](https://docs.dask.org/en/stable/dataframe-design.html#metadata) argument. This makes using Dask for this task challenging. Relatedly, the `ValueError` occurs because `column_name_2` requires only 1 split, and returns a Dask DataFrame with 2 columns, but Dask is expecting a DataFrame with 3 columns.

Here is one solution (building from @Fontanka16's answer) if you *do* know the number of splits ahead of time:

```py
import dask.dataframe as dd
import pandas as pd

ddf = dd.from_pandas(
    pd.DataFrame({
        'column_name_1': ['a^b^c', 'e^f^g', 'h^i'], 'column_name_2': ['j', 'k^l', 'm']
    }), npartitions=2
)

ddf_list = []
num_split_dict = {'column_name_1': 2, 'column_name_2': 1}
for col, num_splits in num_split_dict.items():
    split_df = ddf[col].str.split('^', n=num_splits, expand=True).add_prefix(f'{col}_')
    ddf_list.append(split_df)
new_ddf = dd.concat([ddf] + ddf_list, axis=1)
new_ddf.compute()
```